# Django formset: show forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I have the following models:

```
class DecompositionGoal(Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parent = ForeignKey(Goal, related_name='related_src')
    child = ForeignKey(Goal, related_name='related_dst')
```

In `Goal` model there is a boolean field `is_quantitative`.

For the given `parent` I want to change `is_quantitative` field for each `child`.

Don't know how to apply `inlineformset` for this.

What are the ways of accomplishing this task?

Comment: I don't think you can use inline formsets here, because the `Goal` model does not have a foreign key to the parent model. I would try using a model formset factory instead.

Comment: Can you show how can this be done?

Comment: Sorry, I can't write a full example for you. Give it a go and add more detail to your question when you get stuck.

Comment: I think I will figure it out. Thank you for your help!